# iOS 64-bit requirement iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, objective-c, 32bit-64bit

I inherited an old project, with old 3rd party frameworks in there.
It runs fine on my iPhone 6, and I have successfully archived the app for AdHoc deployment.
However, when I try to submit the app to the App Store, i get an error about the missing 64bit architecture.
When I add Arm64 to architectures and valid architectures in the Build Settings of my target (and project for that matter), the app won't compile, since one of the frameworks is "missing required architecture arm64". Linking then fails, and I cannot create an archive.

Since some of the above mentioned settings have a kind of voodoo touch to them for me, I hope that there is a combination of settings, that somehow takes 32-bit code, but presents it after compiling as 64 bit.

I had a look at the latest version of the framework that is causing the issue, but its file structure and naming convention is completely different, so an upgrade will take quite a lot of work.

Does any of you have some suggestions?

thanks

Comment: "so an upgrade will take quite a lot of work" Then do that work. You cannot _pretend_ that you are not missing the 64-bit slice!

Comment: @matt: is that the only way forward? I was hoping for an interim quick fix. Interestingly, half a year ago, I managed to submit this very app.

Comment: Because this was not a requirement then. But now it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I hope that there is a combination of settings, that somehow takes 32-bit code, but presents it after compiling as 64 bit.

You seem to be asking to cheat. You can't cheat. It is [now a *requirement*](http://9to5mac.com/2014/12/17/apple-reminds-developers-about-64-bit-ios-app-store-requirement-app-updates-now-must-also-comply-by-june/) that apps be 64-bit. This requirement started in June 2015. Apple signalled this change well in advance, and you yourself, as a developer, received at least one email warning you about it!

If you submitted an earlier version of your app prior to that time, it was not a requirement. But now it is.

Comment: On january 22 2016, I created an archive of this project that I successfully submitted to iTunes Connect. Same app, same settings, same framework.

Comment: Hey, it's Apple. Maybe they provided an additional grace period. Maybe their testing / analysis procedure didn't detect this as an issue. I don't speak for the Borg, I just grapple with them like everybody else. :)

Comment: In the end work = work = money = money. But upgrading a framework is not a very interesting task.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a compiled library that only comes in a 32 bit version, there is nothing you can do.

Most libraries on iOS come as source code, so all you need to do is find the right place to make them compile as 64 bit code. You may need to look where the library comes from and maybe download a new version. If there is no new version available, you may have to write the code yourself or download a different library. Some developers have the bad habit of importing a huge library for a single ten line method, so if you are lucky, rewriting the missing code may not be much effort.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have three options: 1 - it might simply be an error in the build settings; 2 - remove 64 bit architectures; or 3 - recompile the old framework(s) for 64-bit compatibility.

In case you simply have an error somewhere in your build settings. Have you checked that the different release schemes are set correctly like so:

[image]

Sometimes changing the `Build Active Architecture Only` flag to `no` has helped me too:

[image]

Just make sure that you click on the disclosure triangle to set the correct settings for each scheme (debug & release).

In terms of the old framework, is it manually included or do you use something like CocoaPods? I know that CocoaPods can have its own settings for building for only armv7 and armv7s and not arm64.

[Apple's guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit.html) for converting an existing app to 64-bit might be useful.

Comment: Thanks, I will go through the guidelines. In the mean time, I have looked at all these settings, changed them, re-changed them, but the end result is that the app either doesn't compile, or is rejected by iTunes connect.

Comment: @Sjakelien I feel your pain. Would you be able to provide more detail (perhaps a screenshot or copy & paste) of where the linker fails?